# How to model sub sections in a relational database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, data-modeling

I'd like to model genres of games in a way such that genres can have sub-sections e.g.
**Genre      |   Sub Genre**
Action     >   Action Adventure
Action     >   Shooter
Simulation >   Vehicle simulation
As you can imagine I don't what Shooter to be a sub section of Simulation as well, etc.

I was thinking of doing this but is there a better way:
**Genres** (Genre{PK}, SubGenre{FK})
**SubGenre** (SubGenre{PK}, Genre{FK})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably create the Genres and SubGenres tables like:

**Genres** (GenreID{PK}, GenreName)

**SubGenre** (SubGenreID{PK}, GenreID{FK}, SubGenreName)

There is no reason to have the SubGenre as an FK in your Genres table. That limits you to exactly one genre per subgenre.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
Genres 
------
Genre PK 


SubGenres
---------
SubGenre  PK
Genre        FK
```

or this (if there is a chance for 2 Genres having Subgenres with same name), for example:

Action > Space
Simulation > Space

```
Genres 
------
Genre PK 


SubGenres
---------
Genre     PK  FK
SubGenre  PK
```

Comment: In your second example, in the instance of 2 genres having subgenres with the same name, it would probably be better to rename your subgenres table to genres_subgenres and use it as junction table to your first definition of subgenres - creating a M:M relationship.

Comment: @gangreen: Actually, it's like an `M:M` relationship as it is, too. With only the junction table and without the second table :)

Comment: Right, right. I guess I was getting at the normal form/update anomaly issues one might encounter. E.g., if two genres shared the subgenre "Space", but it was misspelled "Spaec"; it would be possible to correct the spelling in one record, but not the other. Then again, perhaps in some cases that would be preferable to allow that to happen...